# thumbnails in image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Please take a look at [my codepen](http://codepen.io/tbeckett24/pen/VLwmWy):

**html**

```
<body>
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s30.postimg.org/4yboplkxd/dotty.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/4fg0tjk5r/goldy.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s12.postimg.org/5lsgrnfcd/oily.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/mcpamwhaf/splashy.jpg" width="100" height="100"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="large-image"><div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.thumbnails {
  width: 250px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  margin: 2px;      
}

img:hover {
 border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

What I currently have is 4 scales down images in a div with the class="thumbnails".

What I'm looking to achieve is when I click on a thumbnail pictures the I want a larger image to show in the div with class="large-image".

Comment: I'm quite new to this website and maybe I'm getting it wrong. But everytime I put up a question someone has to moan and I can't post for another few days. I can't work this out, how is this constructive or needed. I've not falsed you to answer. What really gets me is that there are some people that are more than happy to help who taught me alot with there advice but others for no reason come along and try and punish me for asking a question. Try to understand not everyone is a talented as you and what seems a stupid question really helps others out

Comment: [@troy beckett](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4730663/troy-beckett) I think the down votes are coming from you not putting more relevant code into your question and explaining where the problem is.  I do have a problem with the down-voter not having the courtesy to explain to you why they down-voted your question.  Everyones idea of effort is a little different, so it should be explained.  Once you edit, they could remove their down-vote. [Use this link for how you should write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

After including the jQuery library, add the following JS:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $("div.large-image").empty().append($(this).clone().css('width',1000));
})
```

This adds an event listener to all your images, which fires when they're clicked on. It then removes all the contents of the `.large-image` div and appends a copy of your `img` element.

Comment: Thanks, alot for your really quick reply, what your answer does is great but it completely clones the thumbnail. I'm looking to put a larger version of the image in the large-image div. But thanks for your reply it's a great start for me to get going with.

Answer (score 0):

Append an imag tag just with the image source of the clicked image, like below:

```
$("img").click(function() {
    $("div.large-image").empty().append(
        $("<img/>", { src: this.src })
    );
})
```

Demo@[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNYgOW)

Comment: can I just ask for advice on how you think I can improve my jquery and javascript skills. You guys are obviously very good and I would like to get alot better. So I was wondering if there was anyway you would advise leaning it or it it just practise

Comment: First of all, I hope my answer helped you. As for learning JS/jQuery, it's about a lot of reading (online) and put them into practice as and when you come across something. Just reading won't help.

Comment: so i went away and tried adding code so that everytime a thumbnail is clicked the large image has so text underneath to describe the pic. heres my current codepen [link](http://codepen.io/tbeckett24/pen/VLwmWy). I like it but it doesn't really give me any freedom on seperating or manipulating the text being used in the alt tag. Would you suggest another way? Just so we are clear I'm not expecting complete answers as I know you have better things to do with your time. Just looking for advice or direction??

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aObWbN) what you were talking about? Or did you want an option to enter text elsewhere than alt?

Comment: nah yours works pretty much the same way i've got it currently. But if you notice on the picture with artist 1 written underneath I have a ref number next it and I kind of wanted to make it seperate from the artist name. But with the way I'm using alt to get the text underneath I'm not sure if individual styling of words is possible

Comment: You may want to use `data-*` atributes to seggregate your data. Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJdmwK)